# Remove ''\n" from list of strings while file reading in Python

Tags: python, list, parsing, file-handling

```
def files_to_dict(folder_name):
    list_of_files = os.listdir("./"+folder_name) #read file names of current dir in list
    newDict=dict()
    for year in (list_of_files):
        if(year!=".ipynb_checkpoints"):
            ofile = open("./"+folder_name+"/"+year,"r")
            data = ofile.read().split(',')

    return data
```

I am trying to remove all delimiters while reading file into a list, including '\n'. I have tried using the above method but it gives the output like

> 'Emma',
>    'F',
>    '20799\nOlivia',
>    'F',
>    '19674\nSophia',
>    'F',
>    '18490\nIsabella',
>    'F',
>    '16950\nAva',

The list goes on will the same pattern.
I want to remove the '\n' from the middle of the string in a list. I want to find an efficient solution which doesn't involve running a loop on the entire list again and removing the '\n' from each index.

Expexted Output:

> 'Emma',
>    'F',
>    '20799', 'Olivia',
>    'F',
>    '19674', 'Sophia',
>    'F',
>    '18490', 'Isabella',
>    'F',
>    '16950', 'Ava',

Comment: Have you considered the csv library? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: `mystring.replace("\n", " ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to replace the "\n" characters with a delimiter rather than removing them:

```
def files_to_dict(folder_name):
    list_of_files = os.listdir("./"+folder_name) #read file names of current dir in list
    newDict=dict()
    for year in (list_of_files):
        if(year!=".ipynb_checkpoints"):
            with open("./"+folder_name+"/"+year,"r") as ofile:
                data = ofile.read().replace('\n', ',').split(',')
                return data
```

Comment: Last thing, I know this is how OP's code is also, but you never close the files... Either `close` them, or better yet, use `with`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your files look like, but I see you're never using newDict so you just return the last file what was processed

Try seeing if the following is closer to what you want

```
with open("./"+folder_name+"/"+year) as ofile:
    data_lines = [s.rstrip() for s in ofile.readlines()] 
    # would be better if you used csv module 
    data = [s.split(',') for s in data_lines]
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's  very simple ,use split() instead of split(',') in your code.I modified  your code and it is shown below:-

```
def files_to_dict(folder_name):
list_of_files = os.listdir("./"+folder_name) #read file names of current dir in list
newDict=dict()
for year in (list_of_files):
    if(year!=".ipynb_checkpoints"):
        ofile = open("./"+folder_name+"/"+year,"r")
        data = ofile.read().split()

return data
```

Please refer to the following code and output if any more confusion is there.To understand easily i executed the below code based on your input

**code:**

```
fh=open("trystack.txt",'r')
for line in fh:
    lines=fh.read().split()
    print(lines)  
fh.close()
```

**output:**

['Olivia', 'F', '19674', 'Sophia', 'F', '18490', 'Isabella', 'F', '16950']

My text file **trystack.txt**  contains:

Emma F 20799

Olivia F 19674

Sophia F 18490

Isabella F 16950

This will help you in achieving what you need i.e removing '\n'

ThankYou

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code but its returning the whole line as a single sentence rather than splitting for e.g it turns this line Emma, F, 20799 into an entire string i.e. "Emma, F, 20799"

Comment: but see my code in which trystack.txt file i have used.It doesn't contain '\n' and it resembles with your output.

Comment: oh ok, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use `data.strip()` to remove ‘\n’ from a string

Answer (score -1):

```
data =  'Emma', 'F', '20799\nOlivia', 'F', '19674\nSophia', 'F', '18490\nIsabella', 'F', '16950\nAva','Emma', 'F', '20799\nOlivia', 'F', '19674\nSophia', 'F', '18490\nIsabella', 'F', '16950\nAva'
sum((s.split('\n') for s in data), [])
```

['Emma', 'F', '20799', 'Olivia', 'F', '19674', 'Sophia', 'F', '18490', 'Isabella', 'F', '16950', 'Ava', 'Emma', 'F', '20799', 'Olivia', 'F', '19674', 'Sophia', 'F', '18490', 'Isabella', 'F', '16950', 'Ava']

or if it is a string like this below:

data =  "'Emma', 'F', '20799\nOlivia', 'F', '19674\nSophia', 'F', '18490\nIsabella', 'F', '16950\nAva','Emma', 'F', '20799\nOlivia', 'F', '19674\nSophia', 'F', '18490\nIsabella', 'F', '16950\nAva'"

```
import re
re.findall(r"[\w]+", data)
```

['Emma', 'F', '20799', 'Olivia', 'F', '19674', 'Sophia', 'F', '18490', 'Isabella', 'F', '16950', 'Ava', 'Emma', 'F', '20799', 'Olivia', 'F', '19674', 'Sophia', 'F', '18490', 'Isabella', 'F', '16950', 'Ava']

Comment: This isn't valid code and none of the strings have new lines

Comment: @cricket_007 why isn't it valid? It is definetly not the best explained code, but perfectly valid

Comment: @Tomer there's no brackets on the list?

Comment: @cricket_007 It's not a list. It's a tuple

Comment: i missed the point splitting the inner data i thought you just wanted to the remove \n at first.